# Linear time algorithm for finding value of MST in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Is there a linear `О(n+m)` time algorithm for finding just the value `r` of the minimum spanning tree of a given graph `G(V,E)`? We do not want to find that MST, just the sum of its edges.

I have searched for solution of the problem, but Kruskal's and Prim's algorithms are with higher complexity because of the comparison structures they use(`UnionFind(Kruskal)` and `PQ(Prim)`). Also they find the MST, which is not desired and maybe there is faster way to find only `r`.

Comment: By liner I mean О(n+m) or О(V+E).

Comment: Kruskal's complexity is higher because of sorting rather than Union-Find. If you were able to sort edges in linear time (bucket/counting/radix sort) then you could consider your algorithm as linear because you can assume that log* is at most equal to 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your edges are integer weighted, there is a linear algorithm from Ferdman and Willard in the following publication:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000005800649

There is also a randomize linear time algorithm from Karger, Klein and Tarjan using a comparaison model:
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=201019.201022

I belive that in the comparaison model Chazelle's algorithm using soft heap is the fastest deterministic one, but it's not a linear one (you have a inverse Akermann overhead).

Answer (score 2):

No. There's no linear solution.

You can optimize Kruskal with [disjoin-set optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) and radix/counting sort so that the complexity is O(E alpha(V)) where alpha is a very slow growing inverse Akermann function. For most datasets this will be almost indistinguishable from linear. At this point you can probably gain more at run-time by optimizing the code rather than the algorithm.